# Out of Memory Error-Android

Tags: android, csv, out-of-memory

Currently I am working on an Android application in which I need to insert data in Csv file to db. That Csv file had more than 2.5 millions data.

Is there any way to convert Csv file directly to .db format?

> Info: Size of the Csv file is 8 Mb.

What I Tried:

Initially I try to parse Csv file in my application and insert 1000 data and done it successfully. But while retrieve and store the data in List I got OutOfMemoryError.

Is there any way to sort it out?

Comment: What is `2.5lakhs`? How have you tried to read the file?

Comment: `2.5lahks` reads like `bazzilions` indeed >)

Comment: 250000 String objects.Yes I tried but it take too much time so i create another file with 1000 data.Actually the problem occurs when i store 1000 objects in List.

Answer (score 2):

You should not load the whole file at one into the memory. Use a *streaming* approach, where you process the file line-by-line (with `LineNumberReader` for example) and process each line individually, so that the JVM has to keep only the actual line in RAM.

You can also use batches of, say 1000 lines to process in one sit. That gives you the speed (less db-transactions should be made) while keeping the memory footprint at minimum.

Also try maximazing the objects' reuse rate, avoid unnecessary creation.

Comment: Actually the problem occurs when i store 1000 objects in List.Is there anything like an ArrayList object can store only some limited amount of data? Does Out of memory error occurs due to memory leak?if yes then does adding objects to List cause memory leak?

Comment: dont't store the objects in the list forever. Flush the list after each 100 lines of your csv file (with `list.clear()`). You get OOE not because of memory leak, but because of memory (heap?) limitations of android.